# The method 'addAll' isn't defined for the class 'Future<List<Post>>'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

trying create infinitive loading list

```
Future<List<Post>> fetchPost(page) async {
  final response =
  await http.get(Uri.parse('url?page=' + page.toString()));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final parsed = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return parsed.map<Post>((json) => Post.fromMap(json)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load');
  }
}
```

and then in scroll listener

```
_scrollListener() {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        print("comes to bottom");
        isLoading = true;

        if (isLoading) {
          print("RUNNING LOAD MORE");

          pageCount = pageCount + 1;
          var oldPost = fetchPost(pageCount);
          futurePost = futurePost.addAll(oldPost);
        }

      });
    }
  }
```

and get error The method 'addAll' isn't defined for the class 'Future<List>'

can't find information about it and in lot's of exaples this method used like default

Answer (score 2):

`fetchPost` is async, so it returns a `Future`, so you need to `await` its result. But this isn't allowed because the anonymous function passed to `setState` isn't `async`, and you shouldn't make it `async` either because all side effects are supposed to have happened as soon as that function returns.

Instead, refactor your code to do only the very minimal amount of work inside the `setState` callback:

```
_scrollListener() async {
    if (_scrollController.offset >=
        _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
      print("comes to bottom");
      isLoading = true;

      if (isLoading) {
        print("RUNNING LOAD MORE");

        pageCount = pageCount + 1;
        var oldPost = await fetchPost(pageCount);
        setState(() {
          futurePost = futurePost.addAll(oldPost);
        });
      }

    }
  }
```

Comment: nope(  I tryed this example, and still has erro on addAll

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/main.dart:176:37: Error: The method 'addAll' isn't defined for the class 'Future<List<Post>>'.

Comment: I print out futurePost

print(futurePost);
        setState(() {
          //futurePost = futurePost.addAll(oldPost);
        });
and it says 

Instance of 'Future<List<Post>>'

Comment: Did you `await` the result of `fetchPost(pageCount)`?

Comment: A value of type 'List<Post>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Future<List<Post>>'.

I have 
late Future<List<Post>> futurePost;
-----------------------
futurePost = fetchPost(pageCount);
-------------------------
child: FutureBuilder<List<Post>>(
                          future: futurePost,
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {

if I adding await, getting many errors because futurePost become  List and FutureBuilder<List<Post>>( not acsept  that

Comment: I suggest you read up on how futures and `setState` work. It's not useful to store just the `Future`, you really need to store its result, as in `List<Post> post;`. How else would you access the state when you render your widget?